# "Forbidden" error when trying to delete kubernetes pods

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-go-client

I'm trying to delete kubernetes pod via `go-client` library using the following code:

```
err := ks.clientset.CoreV1().Pods(kubeData.PodNamespace).Delete(context.Background(), kubeData.PodName, metav1.DeleteOptions{})
if err != nil {
  log.Fatal(err)
}
```

However receiving an error:

> pods "app-name" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:app-name" cannot delete resource "pods" in API group "" in the namespace "default""

Here is the serviceaccount.yaml:

```
{{- $sa := print .Release.Name "-" .Values.serviceAccount -}}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: {{ $sa }}
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}

---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: {{ $sa }}
rules:
  - apiGroups: ["apps"]
    verbs: ["patch", "get", "list"]
    resources:
      - deployments
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: {{ $sa }}
rules:
  - apiGroups: ["apps"]
    verbs: ["delete", "get", "list"]
    resources:
      - pods
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: {{ $sa }}
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: {{ $sa }}
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: {{ $sa }}
```

Looks like something related to user permissions, however not sure how to properly configure it.
Thanks.

Comment: Could you please share the `RoleBinding`/`ClusterRoleBinding` associated with the `ClusterRole` and your `ServiceAccount`?

Comment: @DawidKruk updated the question, there should be `Role` instead of `ClusterRole`, my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the error:

`pods "app-name" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:app-name" cannot delete resource "pods" in API group "" in the namespace "default""`

The important part is: **`in API group ""`**

Take a look on your manifest:

```yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: {{ $sa }}
rules:
  # - apiGroups: ["apps"] # <-- BAD!
  - apiGroups: [""] # <-- GOOD!
    verbs: ["delete", "get", "list"]
    resources:
      - pods
```

This definition is specifying that a resource `Pod` is in the `apiGroup: apps` which is not correct and `""` should be used instead.

More on that you can read here:

- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Reference: Using API: API Groups](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/#api-groups)*

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Also I had wrongly formatted `serviceaccount.yaml`: apiGroups for resources pods and deployments should be under the same rules rather that separate.